# On squared Integral points of a Parabola

Tags: geometry, modular-arithmetic

I am puzzling about one pretty weird question which I cannot find in Internet.

Let $y=ax^2+bx+c$ a parabola where of course $x \in\mathbb R$ and $a,b,c \neq 0$

It's easy to understand that for any $x  \in\mathbb N$ the values of $y$ are integer numbers too.

But would it be possible to “know” which $x \in\mathbb N$ give $y \in\mathbb N$ values (so we have integral points) AND $y$ is a square ? (So $\sqrt{y} \in\mathbb N$) ?

Sorry for the naive approach but this is my first post here and my first attempt to use MathJax…

Thanks,
Davinator

Comment: That would be equivalent to some kind of Pell-like equation.

Comment: Thanks Ivan, which ones ?

Comment: @Davinator Welcome to Math SE. You state that "for any $x  \in\mathbb N$ the values of $y$ are integer numbers too". As such, this implicitly means the $a,b,c$ values must at least be integers. However, apart from being non-zero as stated, are there any other restrictions, e.g., are you requiring that any or all of them need to be positive?

Comment: Hi John, thanks for your reply. I forgot to mention the things you wrote.
Yes, a,b,c are Integers , a is positive, the others can be positive or negative.

Comment: Do you want to know which $y \in \mathbb{N}$ give $x$ values, where $x \in \mathbb{N}$?

Comment: Hi YNK, no, I need to know which natural number x gives a natural number y where y is a squared number

Comment: @Davinator Thanks for clarifying your requirement. But, don't forget to add that @ symbol in front of the name of the person, to whom your are addressing your answer.   If you don't do that, MSE cannot notify that person.